# Salesforce JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, salesforce, sql-workbench-j

I am trying to establish a connection with Salesforce via JDBC driver which I got from  https://github.com/ascendix/salesforce-jdbc

I have set up this driver in SQLWorkbench tool. The connection is successful. [image] But when I execute any query like **SELECT Id from Account** it fails with error

Detail Log:

```
2019-08-14 00:03:14 INFO  Creating new connection for [{Default group}/SFJDBC  -- https://github.com/ascendix/salesforce-jdbc] for driver=com.ascendix.jdbc.salesforce.ForceDriver and URL=[jdbc:ascendix:salesforce://https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0;user=xyz;password=xyz]
2019-08-14 00:03:16 INFO  WbWin-1 TAB-1: Using DBID=ascendix_jdbc_driver_for_salesforce 
2019-08-14 00:03:16 INFO  WbWin-1 TAB-1: Using identifier quote character: " 
2019-08-14 00:03:16 INFO  WbWin-1 TAB-1: Using search string escape character:  
2019-08-14 00:03:16 WARN  WbWin-1 TAB-1: The driver did not return any table types using getTableTypes(). Using default values: [TABLE, VIEW] 
2019-08-14 00:03:16 INFO  WbWin-1 TAB-1: Using catalog separator: . 
2019-08-14 00:03:16 INFO  Connected to: [Ascendix JDBC driver for Salesforce], Database version info: [39], Database version number: [39.0], Driver version: [1.1], JDBC version: [4.0], ID: [WbWin-1 TAB-1] 
2019-08-14 00:03:19 WARN  The JDBC driver does not support the setMaxRows() function! (null) 
2019-08-14 00:03:19 ERROR Error executing:
SELECT Id from Account
   java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at workbench.sql.commands.SelectCommand.execute(SelectCommand.java:131)
    at workbench.sql.StatementRunner.runStatement(StatementRunner.java:552)
    at workbench.gui.sql.SqlPanel.displayResult(SqlPanel.java:3468)
    at workbench.gui.sql.SqlPanel.runStatement(SqlPanel.java:2199)
    at workbench.gui.sql.SqlPanel$16.run(SqlPanel.java:2137)
```

I checked the Database Explorer-> Objects tab has a list of all objects (Account, Contact, etc.) But when I clicked on Data tab to check the data there also got the same above error.

So I even tried to write JDBC code in eclipse there also connection was successful but on executing code I got below error

```
 Connected to Salesforce.
com.ascendix.jdbc.salesforce.ForceConnection createStatement
INFO: createStatement
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SFJDBC.main(SFJDBC.java:77)
```

Code for Reference:

```
try 
    {

        final String UserName = "user";

        final String Password = "password";

        String dbURL = "jdbc:ascendix:salesforce://login.salesforce.com";
        String dbUsername = "xyz";
        String dbPassword = "xyz";

        java.util.Properties connProperties = new java.util.Properties();
        connProperties.put(UserName, dbUsername);
        connProperties.put(Password, dbPassword);

        Class.forName("com.ascendix.jdbc.salesforce.ForceDriver");
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put(UserName,dbUsername);
        connectionProps.put(Password,dbPassword);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, connectionProps);
        System.out.println(connection.toString());

        if(!connection.isClosed())
        {
            System.out.println("Connected to Salesforce.");

            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Id FROM ACCOUNT");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        }   

    } 



    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

**I am more concerned with making driver work for SQL Workbench. Any help to resolve this will be really appreciated.**

**** UPDATE ****

Thanks to @Mark Rotteveel based on his suggestion made changes to the code and post that code was successful. But need to make this driver work in SQL Workbench as well.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Id FROM Account limit 3");
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Id FROM Account limit 3");
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next())
            {
                 System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
            }
```

Comment: Which line is line 77 in your code where the NPE is thrown? It sounds like that JDBC driver is not compliant with the JDBC specification and returns `null` at points where a well-behaved JDBC driver would throw a SQLException or return a non-null object. You will need to report a bug to whoever wrote that driver.

Comment: Line 77 ->  rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Id FROM ACCOUNT");

Comment: That would suggest `connection.createStatement()` returns `null`, which is a violation of the JDBC specification: report a bug with the author of this driver. See also [this line in the implementation](https://github.com/ascendix/salesforce-jdbc/blob/master/sf-jdbc-driver/src/main/java/com/ascendix/jdbc/salesforce/connection/ForceConnection.java#L76). Workaround seems to be to use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MarkRotteveel  changing to PreparedStatment worked. But like I had said my actual use case is to use this JDBC Driver(Jar) in SQL Workbench tool. Any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: You probably can't, other than reporting a bug to the author of that JDBC driver and hoping they fix it.

Comment: Please send the complete (!) logfile to the SQL Workbench support address (Help --> Contact the author). This wouldn't be the first JDBC driver that isn't implementing everything I expect in SQL Workbench. But usually there is a workaround that I can implement

Comment: @SQLWorkbenchJ I have sent mail to support. And also updated my post with detail log for your reference.

Comment: Looking at the logfile and your sample code, it seems pretty clear that `Connection.createStatement()` simply does not work with that driver. That is a deficiency that I did not expect. I am sorry, but there is nothing you can do with the SQL Workbench configuration to workaround that bug.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the log. So is there any other Open Source JDBC driver for Salesforce ?